# Calculate the area of a triangular field, knowing that two and 1 angle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Hello so this problem came up while I was studying trig. and I seem a bit stuck:

Calculate the area of a triangular field, knowing that two of its sides measure $80$ m and $130$ m and between them is an angle of $70°$.

To solve this problem I drew altitude and[image: Diagram]

So with this diagram I used the $Z$ side as common to find two equations using $\sin$:
$$\sin x= Z/80$$
$$\sin y=Z/130$$

which gives

$$Z=\sin x*80$$
$$Z=\sin y*130$$

and also $70+x+y=180$,
so $x+y=110$.

So now I have two equations with two unknowns but I don't know how to solve them because the unknowns are in $\sin$.

Note: I have not yet learned about laws of $\sin$, $\cos$... So is there a way to solve this question without using such formulas??

Comment: Drop a perpendicular *from the bottom left vertex* to the opposite side. (Forget about the perpendicular you drew.) You will find that this altitude has length $80\sin(70^\circ)$, and now you can find the area of your big triangle using half base times height.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so the height will be equal= 75.2 then area= 1/2(130)(75.2)= 4886

Comment: Yes, to the nearest integer. I get about $4886.4016$, and don't know what kind of rounding is expected in your course.